# can you change all this thing (JCheckBox) go to array and loop?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane, jcheckbox

I am doing some GUI and I use `JCheckBox`. I am wondering if this all can be do in an array and loop? It's so tiring to change every single thing.

If you can help me I'd love to hear.

```
if (box1.isSelected())
    k = 40;
if (box2.isSelected())
    l = 30;
if (box3.isSelected())
    m = 20;
if (box4.isSelected())
    n = 10;
if (box5.isSelected())
    o = 10;
if (box6.isSelected())
    p = 10;
if (box7.isSelected())
    q = 10;
if (box8.isSelected())
    r = 10;
if (box9.isSelected())
    j = 10;
if (box10.isSelected())
    i =10;

s = "Price for this is RM" + 
        (k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + j + i);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
```

Comment: Actually you need an `array` **and** a `loop`. Create array of your `JCheckBox` objects and calculate your total iterating trough this array.

Comment: how to create array and loop to JCheckBox ?

Comment: Do you know how to create *any* Java array?

Comment: if the normal one i know something like

int[] num = new num[10];

Comment: Good. `JCheckBox num = new JCheckBox[10];` no difference

Comment: See [Array of Objects](http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/array-of-objects) and [Processing Arrays using Loops](http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/processing-arrays-using-loops). That should be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is this:

```
JCheckBox[] checkboxesArray = new JCheckBox[10];
int i, count;

for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    /* display a checkbox... */

/* Finished displaying checkboxes, now you wait for user to finish input... */

for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    if (checkboxesArray[i].isSelected())
        count += 10;
}
s = "Price for this is RM " + count;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
```

Comment: and the input for each box ? where i need to put ?

Comment: @LukmanAlHakim: you should display the checkboxes where I put my first `for` loop, see the comments. You can reference them as checkboxesArray[i]. Then you could have something like a button, which, when clicked, would invoke the rest of the code. It's all easy to look up in the docs.